# Chaining multiple select components in Tapestry 5.3 (Ajax update)

Tags: java, ajax, forms, tapestry

I’m using tapestry 5.3.7, and I want to use Ajax chaining select form elements : If I choose one option in a select element, another select appear to choose another element based on your first choice. I try a sample in the tapestry doc, and adapted for my project. Despite the fact that my custom code is very close to the sample, I always have the following error :

> **Render queue error in SetupRender[SelectZoneDemo:version]: Component SelectZoneDemo:version must be enclosed by a Form component.**

**Working sample from the doc (Chaining of select components CarMaker)** http://tapestry.apache.org/5.3/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/components/Select.html)

Here is my code :
***Template file (.tml)***

```
<t:form>
    <p>
        <t:errors />
    </p>
    <p>
        <t:select t:id="selectApplicatifs" t:model="selectApplicatifs"
            t:value="selectedApplicatif" validate="required" zone= "VersionZone"
            t:zone="versionZone" t:encoder="ApplicatifDtoEncoder" />
    </p>

    <t:zone t:id="versionZone" id="versionZone">
        <t:if test="selectedApplicatif">
            <p>
                <t:select t:id="version" model="selectVersions" t:encoder="VersionDtoEncoder" />
            </p>
        </t:if>
        <p>
            <t:submit value="literal:Submit" />
        </p>
    </t:zone>

</t:form>
```

***Java file***

```
    @Inject
    private AjaxResponseRenderer ajaxResponseRenderer;

    @Inject
    private IServiceApplicatif serviceApplicatif;

    @Inject
    private SelectModelFactory selectModelFactory;

    @Property
    @Persist
    private SelectModel selectApplicatifs;

    @Property
    @Persist
    private String version;

    @Property
    @Persist
    private SelectModel selectVersions;

    @Inject
    @Property
    private ApplicatifDtoEncoder applicatifDtoEncoder;

    @Inject
    @Property
    private VersionDtoEncoder versionDtoEncoder;

    @Property
    @Persist
    private ApplicatifDto selectedApplicatif;

    @InjectComponent
    private Zone versionZone;

    public void onActivate() {
        List<ApplicatifDto> listApplicatifs = serviceApplicatif.findAllApplicatifDto();
        List<VersionDto> listVersionApplicatifs = new ArrayList<VersionDto>();
        selectApplicatifs = selectModelFactory.create(listApplicatifs, "nom");
        if (selectVersions == null) {
            selectVersions =   selectModelFactory.create(listVersionApplicatifs,"version");
        }
    }

    public void onValueChangedFromSelectApplicatifs(ApplicatifDto applicatifDto) {

        List<VersionDto> versionList = applicatifDto.getVersionList();
        selectVersions = selectModelFactory.create(versionList,"version");

        ajaxResponseRenderer.addRender(versionZone);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rendering zones within a form via ajax can get tricky as you have discovered. Fields require a [FormSupport](http://tapestry.apache.org/5.3/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/services/FormSupport.html) instance to be on the [Environment](http://tapestry.apache.org/environmental-services.html) stack. This is normally added to the environment as the parent form renders but as you have discovered, when rendering a zone within a form the FormSupport is not available.

Here's a few options:

1. Have a zone that wraps the entire form and update the whole form via ajax
2. Instead of refreshing a zone, use some javascript (via [JavaScriptSupport](http://tapestry.apache.org/5.3/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/services/javascript/JavaScriptSupport.html)) to update the options in an existing select menu
3. Use the [Observe](http://t5stitch-lazan.rhcloud.com/observedemo) mixin to update zones in the form. Instead of using the core tapestry select component, you could render your own select. This might require you to use @RequestParameter to get the values serverside when the form is finally submitted.
4. Use the [FormInjector](http://tapestry.apache.org/5.3/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/components/FormInjector.html). I've never used it myself but I think it somehow spoofs the environmental. I'm not sure how you'd pass the user's selection in the event. I think this component may have also been scrapped in tapestry 5.4.