# Tapestry inject form field after uploading files

Tags: java, forms, tapestry

**Versions :

Tapestry version : 5.3.8

Tapestry-jQuery : 3.4.2**

My project consists of uploading multiple files, write them on the filesystem, create an object wrapper for each file in order to add some additional informations. These informations would be created by the user with a form just after the upload.

Unfortunately, I had the exception  **“element must be enclosed by a form component”** when the zone (inside the form : responsible for handling update when a file was uploaded) was updated.

**Index.java**

```
public class Index
{

    @Component
    private FormInjector injector;

    @Component
    private Form uploadForm;

    @InjectComponent
    private Zone uploadResult;

    @Inject
    private Block uploadFields;

    @Persist
    @Property
    private List uploadedFiles;

    @Persist
    @Property
    private List customFiles;

    @Persist
    @Property
    private CustomFile file;

    @Inject
    private AjaxResponseRenderer ajaxResponseRenderer;

    @Environmental
    private JavaScriptSupport jsSupport;

    @Environmental
    private FormSupport formSupport;

    @OnEvent(component = "injector")
    Block loadUploadFields(){
        return  uploadFields; 
    }

    @OnEvent(component = "uploadFiles", value = JQueryEventConstants.AJAX_UPLOAD)
    void onDocUpload(UploadedFile uploadedFile) {
        CustomFile file = new CustomFile();
        if (uploadedFile != null) {
            if(uploadedFiles==null) { 
                uploadedFiles = new ArrayList();
            }
            uploadedFiles.add(uploadedFile);
            file.setFilename(uploadedFile.getFileName());
            if (customFiles==null) {
                customFiles = new ArrayList();
            }
            customFiles.add(file);
        }
        ajaxResponseRenderer.addRender(uploadResult);
    }

    public void onUploadedFile() {
        jsSupport.addScript("$('#injector').trigger()");
    }

}
```

**Index.tml**

```
<j:ajaxUpload t:id="uploadFiles" t:multiple="true">
</j:ajaxUpload>

<h4>Uploaded Files</h4>
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Version</th>
        <th>Reference</th>
    </thead>
    <t:Form t:id="uploadForm">
        <t:zone t:id="uploadResult" id="uploadResult" elementName="tbody">
            <t:if test="uploadedFiles">
                <t:loop source="customFiles" value="file" element="tr"
                    formState="none">

                    <td>${file.filename}</td>

                    <!-- To inject file.version and file.reference textfield -->
                    <!-- Avoid "must be enclosed by a form component" exception" -->
                    <t:FormInjector t:id="injector" id="injector" />

                    <t:block t:id="uploadFields">
                        <td>
                            <input t:type="TextField" t:value="file.version" t:id="version" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input t:type="TextField" t:value="file.reference" t:id="reference" />
                        </td>
                    </t:block>

                    <!-- Trigger event "uploadedFile" that will call $("#injector").trigger() -->
                    <t:Trigger event="uploadedFile" />
                </t:loop>
            </t:if>
        </t:zone>
    </t:Form>
</table>
</html>
```

With some help from : 
[Updating a zone inside a form in Tapestry 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966750/updating-a-zone-inside-a-form-in-tapestry-5)
I tried to use the FormInjector and Trigger components but I can’t figure out how it works. Now I have the exception : **“No object of type org.apache.tapestry5.services.FormSupport is available from the Environment”**
Any suggestions to make this work ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Nest your `<t:form>` inside your `<t:zone>`. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30031445/chaining-multiple-select-components-in-tapestry-5-3-ajax-update/30099105#30099105)